# Navigate to a website right after installing a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I couldn't find any info on the Internet. I want to open a new tab with my url right away after the plugin is installed. 
It's simple to navigate to a website if the user clicks on my plugin's icon:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) 
{
  chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'http://google.com'}, function(tab) { });
});
```

but how do I do that automatically after installing the plugin and **only once**.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` event, opening the tab only if the `reason` is `update`.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onInstalled